# Istio authorisation returns "Jwks doesn't have key to match kid or alg from Jwt"

Tags: jwt, keycloak, istio

I am trying to implement AuthorizationPolicy to protect an application behind Envoy by JWT authentication (Istio 1.8.3).
JWT was requested in keycloak v 12.0.1

I expected to receive 403 if access the application without JWT in BearToken or with the wrong one,
but, instead,

I am getting `"Jwks doesn't have key to match kid or alg from Jwt"`
while both 'kid' and 'alg' are present in jwks

Here are istio configs

```
apiVersion: 'security.istio.io/v1beta1'
kind: 'RequestAuthentication'
metadata:
  name: jwt-validator
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: api
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "MY_ISS_FROM_JWT"
      # I have tried both jwkUri and jwks
      # 'xxx' is a placeholder
      # jwkswas copiedfrom the jwksUri as is
      # jwksUri: https://xxx
      jwks: |
        {"keys":[{"kid":"xxx","kty":"RSA","alg":"RS256","use":"sig","n":"xxx","e":"AQAB","x5c":["xxx"],"x5t":"xxx","x5t#S256":"xxx"}]}

---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: require-jwt
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: api
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            requestPrincipals: ["MY_ISS_FROM_JWT/<MY_SUB_FROM_JWT>"]
```

Comment: Could you please use the following [tutorial](https://www.istiobyexample.dev/jwt) and verify if it's gonna work correctly? If it''s gonna work correctly then there is something wrong in your configuration files you would have to fix.

Comment: thank you @Jakub
I have found that `issuer` must be a valid and accessible link. I thought it is just an string, which you compare with when reading JWT